# Counting the characters of each line with wc

Tags: shell, text-processing, wc

Is it possible to use wc to count the chars of each line instead of the total amount of chars?

e.g.

```
echo -e foo\\nbar\\nbazz | grep -i ba
```

returns:

```
bar
bazz
```

So why doesn't  `echo -e foo\\nbar\\nbazz | grep ba | wc -m`
return a list of the lengths of those words? (3 and 4)

Suggestions?

P.S.: why are linefeeds counted with `wc -m` ? `wc -l` counts the newlines, so why should `wc -m` count them too?

Comment: That's `wc -c` you are looking for.

Comment: @αғsнιη, `wc -c` counts the bytes while `wc -m` counts the characters, but that won't make a difference in this instance where all characters in that sample are single-byte ones.

Comment: in fact `echo 'Stéphane' | wc -m` =9   but `echo 'Stéphane' | wc -c` =10

Answer (score 22):

`wc` counts over the whole file;
You can use `awk` to process line by line (not counting the line delimiter):

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbazz\n" | grep ba | awk '{print length}'
```

or as `awk` is mostly a superset of `grep`:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbazz\n" | awk '/ba/ {print length}'
```

(note that some `awk` implementations report the number of bytes (like `wc -c`) as opposed to the number of characters (like `wc -m`) and others will count bytes that don't form part of valid characters in addition to the characters (while `wc -m` would ignore them in most implementations))

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

```
for line in $(echo -e foo\\nbar\\nbazz); do echo ${#line}; done
```

Output:

```
3
3
4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the output lines and run `wc` for each:

```
echo -e foo\\nbar\\nbazz | \
grep -i ba | \
while read LINE; do echo $LINE | wc -m; done
```

If you don't want to count the newline characters, you can remove them:

```
echo -e foo\\nbar\\nbazz | \
grep -i ba | \
while read LINE; do echo ${LINE::-1} | wc -m; done
```

(The above assumes there is a newline after after line, so if the last line does not include a trailing newline, the count will be off.)

Comment: This doesn't print the length of each line, it prints the length of the line, minus leading and trailing whitespace, plus the length of the next line if the first line ended with a backslash, and after replacing each whitespace-delimited word on the line by the list of matching file names if it happens to be a wildcard pattern matching that name. Approximately. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters for explanations.

Comment: Besides, [this kind of line-by-line processing in the shell is a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169765#169765), and using an external tool in the loop body combines the worst of both worlds.